# A property about a bounded harmonic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(x,y)$ is a bounded harmonic function function in the unit disk and $f(0,0)=1$. Show that $$\iint_{D}f\left(x,y\right)\left(1-x^{2}-y^{2}\right)dxdy=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

I don't understand why the value of integral has nothing to do with the bounded harmonic function. I want to know what properties of harmonic function make this happen.

Comment: It depends on $f(0,0).$

Comment: @zhw.: $f(0, 0) = 1$ is given.

Comment: Right, so it depends on the value of $f$ at $(0,0).$ I was responding to the OP who said the value of the integral has nothing to do with the bounded harmonic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Substitute *polar coordinates*
$$
 x = r \cos \varphi, y = r \sin \varphi, dxdy = r dr d\varphi
$$
and use the mean-value property of harmonic functions.

(The boundedness is only needed to ensure that the integral exists.)

Answer (score 0):

Using polar coordinates, consider $x= r \cos \theta, y= r \sin \theta, dxdy= r dr d\theta$. By the mean value theorem for harmonic functions and what is given, we have that $$f(0,0)= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) d\theta=1 \implies \int_{0}^{2 \pi} f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) d\theta= 2 \pi.$$ Since the domain of integration is the unit disk $D$, using the above implication, we have that $$\begin{eqnarray*}\iint_{D} f(x,y)(1- x^2 - y^2)dxdy & = &  \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{1} f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)(1- r^2)r dr d\theta \\ & = & \int_{0}^{2 \pi} f(r \cos \theta,r \sin \theta)d \theta \int_{0}^{1}(1- r^2)rdr \\ & = & 2 \pi \int_{0}^{1}(1- r^2)rdr = \frac{\pi}{2}.\end{eqnarray*}$$